# Parsing JSON array in golang with custom types

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse a json array in golang, with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "table1": [
      { "name": "col1", "type": "string"},
      { "name": "col2", "type": "int"},
    ]
  },
  {
    "table2": [
       { "name": "col3", "type": "string"},
       { "name": "col4", "type": "int"},
    ]
  },
  {
    "table3": [
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

The json is supposed to contain schemas of different tables for example.
I have tried the following code, but the Schema returns empty:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type ColumnType struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Type  string `json:"type"`
}

type Schema struct {
    Schema map[string][]ColumnType
}

func main() {

    mocksSchemas, _ := os.Open("parse_config/mock_schema.json")

    var schemas []Schema
    content, err := io.ReadAll(mocksSchemas)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error when reading mock file: ", err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(content, &schemas)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error during Unmarshal(): ", err)
    }

    defer mocksSchemas.Close()
}
```

What am I doing wrong? would appreciate any help on pointing out my mistake
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the source / target JSON, you can use the following type:

```golang
type Schema map[string][]ColumnType
```

Alternatively, you could also use something a bit more easy-to-use:

```golang
type Schema struct {
    Table   string
    Columns []ColumnType
}

func (s Schema) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(map[string][]ColumnType{
        s.Table: s.Columns,
    })
}

func (s *Schema) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var m map[string][]ColumnType
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for k, v := range m {
        s.Table = k
        s.Columns = v
        break
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Perfect! the type worked for me. And thanks for the alternative way, looks very readable and indeed easy to use. appreciate it!